# Java histogram from random generated numbers

Tags: java, histogram

*I am playing with and learning a bit of java, so I'm really a newbi*e ... My problem is - I am generating 5 random numbers from 1 to 5. My program then calculates how many times are number 1, number 2, number 3, number 4 and number 5 generated within these randoms.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int randomNumber;
    int i;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    int p3 = 0;
    int p4 = 0;
    int p5 = 0;
    System.out.println("Random numbers:");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.print(randomNumber);
        if (i < 4) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }

        if (randomNumber == 1) {
            array[0] = p1++;
        } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
            array[1] = p2++;
        } else if (randomNumber == 3) {
            array[2] = p3++;
        } else if (randomNumber == 4) {
            array[3] = p4++;
        } else if (randomNumber == 5) {
            array[4] = p5++;
        }
    }
    //výpis četnosti
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Histogram: "); 

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + (i + 1) + ": " + array[i] + ".");
    }
}
```

The programme acts strange for my understanding. The output is always displaying the real count of the number contained in radom generated bundle exactly minus 1 and I really don't understand why. ... So if there are three times generated number 3's from random generator, my programme show for number three only count "2".

I'd be really grateful for helping me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Read in the docs what the suffix `++` operator does and what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're post-incrementing your count variables.  So, what you assign to your int array bucket the very first time you count is 0.

Instead, you can simplify this by just incrementing the integers in your array like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int randomNumber;
    int i;

    System.out.println("Random numbers:");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.print(randomNumber);
        if (i < 4) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }

        array[randomNumber - 1]++;
    }
    //výpis četnosti
    System.out.println("\n\nHistogram: "); 

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + (i + 1) + ": " + array[i] + ".");
    }
}
```

Running this gives me the following output:

```
Random numbers:
2, 3, 5, 3, 2

Histogram: 
Number 1: 0.
Number 2: 2.
Number 3: 2.
Number 4: 0.
Number 5: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0] = p1++;
```

Is the same as:

```
array[0] = p1;
p1 = p1 + 1;
```

I hope that is enough for you to spot your issue.

Comment: I think I'm aware of the meaning of using ++, still my soltions makes sense to me (I still didn't spot the issue). I've also tried debugging a in the part of filling the array with increments the array realy looked like it contains correct numbers. For example my random numbers were: 1, 4, 1, 2, 4 and the variables p1=2, p2=1, p3=0, p4=2, p5=0..